# Как выбрать значение из массива, в котором меньшее значение в поле?

Tags: php, массивы, случайные-числа

Есть массив

```
 Array
    (
        [802344] => Array
            (
                [id] => 802344
                [quantity] => 9
            )

        [802335] => Array
            (
                [id] => 802335
                [quantity] => 2
            )

        [802347] => Array
            (
                [id] => 802347
                [quantity] => 1
            )

    )
```

надо сравнить значение в поле `[quantity]`, если они все равны то выбрать рандомно из них и вернуть значение  поля `[id]` в переменную, если у кого то больше значение `[quantity]` то исключить это значение и выбрать рандомно из оставшихся значение вернув поле `[id]` в переменную

Comment: сортируем по увеличению uasort (! ошибся) ,  потом отбираем, пока значения одинаковые. потом array_rand

Comment: а вот эти числа - 802344 и тд - нужны?

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так, но писал с телефона сюда, могу ошибиться

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) { return $a['quantity'] - $b['quantity']; } );

$min = null;
$ids = [];
foreach($array as $i) {
     if(!$min) $min = $i['quantity'];
     elseif ($i['quantity'] > $min) break;
     $ids[] = $i['id'];
}

$id = $ids[array_rand($ids)];
```

Comment: сейчас попробую))))

Comment: и это работает !!!!!!! не ошибся, вообще таким людям медали надо давать, которые помогают )))